# Are identifying chords or notes in a song on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

The [**Music: Practice & Theory** Stack Exchange site](http://music.stackexchange.com) does not allow questions around identifying transcriptions (chords, progressions, or notes in a particular song). Is that in scope for this site?

Comment: in which way, the identifying transcriptions (chords, progressions, or notes in a particular song) is different to identify lyrics?

Answer (score 10):

I would say no as there's not really a point on a music fan's site. It dives way too much into actually playing and analyzing music then listening to or consuming it.

Answer (score -2):

After having had a bit more experience with both sites, I'm going to suggest that as music.stackexchange.com doesn't allow these questions, that yes, they should be allowed here.

Comment: Note that this completely contradicts an earlier comment I made!

Comment: That's really not a good reason to put them here... We're two independent sites. What Music SE allows and doesn't allow shouldn't affect us.

Comment: @Dom If someone agrees that such questions could work on SE, then the fact that no other SE site will currently accept them is a logically sound reason to *consider* accepting them here, as you'd be providing a new service that didn't previously exist.

Comment: The point of an SE is to eventually become a library of questions for a group interested in a topic along with user interactively building it and improving it. I can't see transcription working o this SE or any SE that's not completely dedicated to it with a strict scope as there will only be a few who can answer in our group, they are time consuming, and there are infinite one off questions that will be little use to others.