# Are questions about naming certain chord progressions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions

I'm going to be taking an exam later this month (October 2019), and part of the exam will ask me to name a bunch of certain chord progressions.  Most of the progressions that I need to study are long and complicated, and I could not figure out names for half of them.  I need another user to help me name them, but it seems as if naming chord progressions aren't really on-topic here.

So this is my question: **Are questions about naming certain chord progressions on-topic?**  (I really need to find an appropriate site to ask this.)

Comment: Many music fans don't have the knowledge to read sheet music, even less identifying chord progressions.

Comment: Music SE is the place for this kind of question. Note that asking for a transcription of the chords to a piece is off-topic there. But questions like "What is the chord sequence 'ii7 V7 I' called?" are allowed (although **that** particular example will almost certainly be a duplicate).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is going to be a duplicate answer from a previous post about [similar content](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66/are-identifying-chords-or-notes-in-a-song-on-topic/67#67):

> I would say no as there's not really a point on a music fan's site. It
>   dives way too much into actually playing and analyzing music then
>   listening to or consuming it.

This is on topic on Music SE for example [this is a question in the same vein](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/30019/7222).